# What happens behind the scenes when adding a nullable column in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

This question came up today. When you add a column that accepts null values to the end of a table what exactly happens? Does the table get fully rebuilt similar to what happens when you change column order?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

This is a metadata only change in SQL Server 2008. See [Size-of-data operations when adding and removing columns](http://www.sqlmag.com/blog/sql-server-questions-answered-28/sql-server/size-of-data-operations-when-adding-and-removing-columns-137144)

SQL Server 2012 can also add [non nullable columns with a default](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/) without having to update all rows however there are also [some circumstances in 2012](http://rusanu.com/2012/02/16/adding-a-nullable-column-can-update-the-entire-table/) in which adding a nullable column is no longer just a metadata change.